# Почему результат SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables -1?

Tags: c#, sql

Может мне кто-то объяснить в чем моя ошибка, что я получаю результыт от SQL-запроса -1? Вот мой код:

```
    public static void proveIfQueryExecuted(String query, String database)
    {
        String sqlConnectionString = String.Format("Server = server; Database = {0}; Trusted_Connection = True;", database);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
            var result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(query);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("tables exist");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No tables exist");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` -> `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @i-one отметите как ответ?

Comment: @i-one прошу прощения, неправильно выразился. Чтобы вы оформили свой комментарий как ответ, а автор отметил бы как верный. Вдруг кому в дальнейшем пригодится)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае вместо метода `ExecuteNonQuery` следует использовать метод `ExecuteScalar`:

```
var result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar(query);
```

Метод `ExecuteNonQuery` обычно используется для выполнения команд, которые не предполагают возвращения какого-либо результирующего значения.

Тогда как `ExecuteScalar` используется для выполнения команд, предполагающих возвращение какого-либо скалярного результирующего значения.